# SPNEGO on IBM WebSphere Portal 6.1 with https

Tags: ssl, https, kerberos, websphere-portal, spnego

I configured IBM WebSphere Portal 6.1 on WAS7:
SPNEGO, ssl with self signed certificate, default http transport (without Web Server) and changed default ports 10039, 10029 to 80, 443.
After that SPNEGO works fine on http, on https displayed standard login form. Where there may be a mistake?

Comment: Could you answer & accept your answer please? This question lingers in Unanswered status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at this document:
[WebSphere Portal Windows SSO w/SPNEGO](http://www.ardenagopyan.com/downloads/tutorials/WPS-SPNEGO-TAI.pdf)

Mapping the user to the Kerberos Service Principal Name (SPN)
When you run the setspn and the ltpass commands there should be something else that points to HTTPS.

Maybe you need another SPN account for HTTPS.

Good luck.

Comment: Web server SPNs are prefixed with the string "HTTP/". This is regardless of whether the protocol used is HTTP or HTTPS. (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0809_lansche/0809_lansche.html)

Comment: Well then thats odd since we recently setup SSO with SPNEGO by using the document in the supplied link and SSO works just fine for us in HTTP and HTTPS.