# Browser not responding to www-authenticate challenge for bookmarked ssl (https url) to restricted resource

Tags: https, kerberos, weblogic12c, spnego

I have set up SSO using weblogic on windows and Kerberos, It is working fine for the http pages, however I observed a strange behavior on https pages which requires CONFIDENTIAL setting for the transport, It works fine if I first access a page on http which is not configured as secured in web.xml(Transport-Gurantee as None) and then the https page.

But If I try to hit the https url directly which is configured with Transport-Gurantee as CONFIDENTIAL then it shows the Basic Auth Dialog and a 401 Unauthorized response, Looking at the logs I see that the Server responded with the WWW-Authenticate but browser showed the Basic Auth Dialog in response instead of getting the Authorize token.

Does anyone has any idea on what might be issue here, If there is any problem with the browser settings then it would not have worked irrespective of accessing the http url first.

I can see the following error log in weblogic console

```
Malformed request "Can not parse URI from http request". Request parsing    failed, Code: -1
```

Found one of the link here
[SPNEGO on IBM WebSphere Portal 6.1 with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715637/spnego-on-ibm-websphere-portal-6-1-with-https)

For my case it is weblogic 12c , I don't think reinstalling 12c is a valid solution for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it fixed , It turns out to be an issue with the browser configuration , the https://myserver.domain.com was not inside the intranet domain and the control to do that rests with the windows Admin team, once they added it , the https urls are also working fine.